# Unable to retrieve an access token for Google's API using google-api-php-client

Tags: php, access-token

I'm trying to receive an access token from the Google API:

```
$client = new Google_Client();        
$client->setAuthConfig('service-account.json');        
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery');        
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);    
var_dump($client->getAccessToken());
```

I already tried with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` but that returns `null`, too:

```
$client = new Google_Client();       
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service-account.json');        
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();        
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery');        
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
```

Comment: I've cleaned up your question a bit. Please explain more clearly exactly what is wrong. (E.g., you say that the second example "returns `null`, too". Does that mean that `$client->getAccessTokan()` in your first example returns `null`? What is in `service-account.json`?) See [ask].

Comment: Both methods returns NULL

Comment: Now I receive  another error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'json key is missing the type field' in ............/libraries/google-api-client-/vendor/google/auth/src/CredentialsLoader.php:118 Stack trace

Comment: Thi is my json file                                                                                         {"installed":
    {
        "client_id":"446624870044-lsouk9hbm941pl29fqa4ip0s3gn65454.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id":"e3-gaga-555",
        "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
    }
}

Comment: All right... I saw what is happening... My json service account was deprecated. I nedded to download it again, so it came with more vars on json file... The deprecated one has only 3 fields...

Answer (score 0):

All right... I saw what is happening... My json service account file was deprecated. I nedded to download it again, so it came with more vars on json file... The deprecated one has only 3 fields...